# Making shared_ptr in class unable to change object it points to when class object is const

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, constants, shared

I am making a class that shares data between several objects using dynamic memory. The relevant parts of the class are shown below.

```
class StrBlob
{
public:
    StrBlob::StrBlob(std::initializer_list<std::string> il) :
        data(std::make_shared<std::vector<std::string>>(il)) {}
    void push_back(const std::string &t) const { data->push_back(t); }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> dataPtr;
};
```

I understand that by making push_back a const member function, I am saying that this function will not change the member dataPtr. However, the underlying vector that dataPtr points to is not const, as shown by the below code.

```
//The result is foo = {"bar", "foobar"}
const StrBlob foo = {"bar"};
foo.push_back("foobar");
```

Is it possible or even desirable to make the underlying vector const by making the StrBlob object const? Should be something like making dataPtr a pointer to const when the object is const, but I'm not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: You need something like [`propagate_const`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4372.html). Unfortunately, that's only a proposal right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a thin wrapper around `std::shared_ptr` (details omitted like ctor etc):

```
#include <memory>

template< class T > class const_propagated_shared_ptr {
    std::shared_ptr<T> m_ptr;
public:
    T &operator*() { return m_ptr.operator*(); }
    T* operator->() { return m_ptr.operator->(); }
    const T &operator*() const { return m_ptr.operator*(); }
    const T *operator->() const { return m_ptr.operator->(); }
};

class Foobar {
    const_propagated_shared_ptr<int> m_ptr;
public:
    void f1() { *m_ptr = 10; }
    void f2() const { *m_ptr = 10; } // compile error
};
```

But as this is implementation detail of the class (Foobar in this case) I am not sure that it worse the effort, as to let modify data by const method or not can be controlled by class designer.